# SQL Server How to Utilize Pivot in this difficult situation

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I've been reading a lot of posts on here trying to figure out how to use this pivot function and have not had any luck. Either some of the explanations included something unnecessary to me or made it too difficult for to understand because I only recently started teaching myself SQL.

I need to figure out how to Group my dates into one if possible and turn P1, P2, P3... into columns. Making P1-10 into their each individual column is what is most important.

This is what the original SQL Server looks like.. + many other columns that are irrelevant for what I'm trying to do.

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| StationName | Start_Time | Time                |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| P1          | 15         | 2018-06-21 13:37:34 |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| P3          | 69         | 2018-06-21 12:33:55 |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| P4          | 52         | 2018-06-21 13:42:34 |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| P1          | 18         | 2018-06-21 10:37:34 |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| P9          | 78         | 2018-06-21 6:37:34  |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+

This is what I currently have

SELECT Cast(Start_Time AS DATE) AS Date, 
StationName, 
sum(time) AS "Daily Downtime"
FROM A6K_Events
Where StationName Like 'P%'
GROUP BY Cast(Start_Time AS DATE), StationName
Order By Date DESC


+------------+-------------+----------------+
| Date       | StationName | Daily Downtime |
+------------+-------------+----------------+
| 2018-06-21 | P1          | 33             |
+------------+-------------+----------------+
| 2018-06-21 | P3          | 62             |
+------------+-------------+----------------+
| 2018-06-21 | P8          | 1              |
+------------+-------------+----------------+
| 2018-06-21 | P9          | 78             |
+------------+-------------+----------------+
| 2018-06-20 | P1          | 69             |
+------------+-------------+----------------+
| 2018-06-19 | P1          | 52             |
+------------+-------------+----------------+


This is what I would like to have:
+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
| Date       | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | P5 | P6 | P7 | P8 | P9 | P10 |
+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
| 2018-06-21 | 33 |    | 62 |    |    |    |    | 1  | 78 |     |
+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
| 2018-06-20 | 69 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |     |
+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
| 2018-06-19 | 52 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |     |
+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
```

The Numbers filled in would be the Daily Downtime value for that process that day. The end result will be recorded live and contain many dates and various down times.

Thanks for the Help in advance

Edited to add text tables and removed images

Comment: Please do not use images for input/output samples. Use text tables instead; there are great websites that can create them for you. Just one [example](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about that this is my first post. I will work on doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish the output with the following pivot statement.

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT CAST([Start_Date] AS DATE) as [DATE],SUM(TIME) AS [Daily DownTime],STATIONNAME FROM A6K_Events Where StationName Like 'P%' GROUP BY [start_date],STATIONNAME 
) AS S
PIVOT(sum([Daily DownTime]) FOR STATIONNAME IN([P1],[P2],[P3],[P4],[P5],[P6],[P7],[P8],[P9],[P10])) AS PT
```

http://rextester.com/BAXY34111

Comment: I have now added text tables and my current code if that would be more useful in answering the question

Comment: I'm still unable to figure this out i keep getting no column name 'Date'

Comment: Ah i see original column is start_date not date updated.

Comment: Any suggestions? I feel like im not even close to getting it right and have been working on this for a long time

Comment: Yes the issue was I did not start with the column named "Start_date" I went off the table, in your query the field is "Start_date" aliased to [Date]. So I corrected and redid the rextester.

Comment: The original column is Start_Time and I tried to join them together so they are grouped together by each day. There is also no downtime column, it is called time. I replace downtime with time though and it still says no column named 'time' when there is. So I'm still very confused. If you need any more information for helping me solve this let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I added what the original SQL server looks like towards the top of my OP

Comment: I'm now extremely close to solving this my only issue is that it is not grouping the rows into individual days instead its is showing times as well but the rest looks excellent!

Comment: If you want to remove the timestamp just use Cast([Start_Date] as Date) I added to my code snip above.

Comment: It works like a charm. I can't thank you enough for the help haha. Thank you so much.